# Codeigniter how to get all/specific method in current controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, methods, controller

I know this code:

```
$this->router->fetch_class(); // get current controller name
$this->router->fetch_method(); // get current method name
```

What I want to do is get all the method available in current controller or specific controller. Anyone had the same experience? Thank You.

**SOLUTIONS**

I create helper to list all method in the specific controller

```
function list_this_controllers_method_except($controller, $except = array())
{
    $methods = array();

    foreach(get_class_methods($controller) as $method)
    {
        if (!in_array($method, $except))
        {
            $methods[] = $method;
        }
    }

    return $methods;
}
```

Comment: Where do you call controller?? In other controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use native php to get the class methods

```
get_class_methods($this);
```

the $this is the controller being called

Sample only

```
class user extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

                #-------------------------------
                # constructor
                #-------------------------------

                parent::__construct();

                var_dump(get_class_methods($this));

            }

}
```

read on the documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php

Comment: Great I use this php function, but how to not print the specific function like construct and get_instance?

Comment: i think you cannot.. maybe in the return results you can filter out the unneccessary functions you want

Comment: Codeigniter only provides a single method but this native PHP method provides all the existing methods of the class. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

-Oli Soproni B.(https://stackoverflow.com/users/1944946/oli-soproni-b)

> Thanks I have used it like this:

```
class user extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

                #-------------------------------
                # constructor
                #-------------------------------

                parent::__construct();

                $methodList = get_class_methods($this);
                foreach ($methodList as $key => $value) {
                 if($value!="__construct"&&$value!="get_instance"&&$value!="index") {
            echo "$value"."\n";
                 }

                }

            }

}
```

[junior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110574/junior)

Answer (score 0):

Try This test function in controller

```
    public function test()
    {   
     $this->load->helper('file');
     $controllers = get_filenames( APPPATH . 'controllers/' ); 

    foreach( $controllers as $k => $v )
    {
        if( strpos( $v, '.php' ) === FALSE)
        {
            unset( $controllers[$k] );
        }
    }

    echo '<ul>';

    foreach( $controllers as $controller )
    {
        echo '<li>' . $controller . '<ul>';

        include_once APPPATH . 'controllers/' . $controller;

        $methods = get_class_methods( str_replace( '.php', '', $controller ) );

        foreach( $methods as $method )
        {
            echo '<li>' . $method . '</li>';
        }

        echo '</ul></li>';
    }

    echo '</ul>'; 
}
```